# Hello - Help Shiro

Tags: java, web, shiro

my app dont ready shiro.ini. I'm using a VRaptor framework , just not this slow shiro.ini . this on the classpath and does not read .

```
public LoginController()  {
   Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory();
   SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
   SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
}
public boolean autenticar(String email, String password, Boolean rememberMe) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(email, password);
    token.setRememberMe(true);
    Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

    try {
        subject.login(token);

    } catch ( UnknownAccountException uae ) { 
        System.out.println(uae.getMessage());
    } catch ( IncorrectCredentialsException ice ) {
        System.out.println(ice.getMessage());
    } catch ( LockedAccountException lae ) {
        System.out.println(lae.getMessage());
    } catch ( ExcessiveAttemptsException eae ){
        System.out.println(eae.getMessage());
    }
    result.redirectTo(LoginController.class).admin();
    return false;
}
```

src/main/webapp/web-inf/shiro.ini

I use a framework called vraptor. I put the shiro dependencies and the .ini file, it this error.

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/vraptor-andre] threw exception [net.vidageek.mirror.exception.ReflectionProviderException: Could not invoke method autenticar] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error:  No realms have been configured!  One or more realms must be present to execute an authentication attempt.
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.assertRealmsConfigured(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:161)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:264)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
    at br.com.genius.shiro.controller.LoginController.autenticar(LoginController.java:55)
```

shiro.ini

`[main]`

```
authc.loginUrl = /login
jdbcRealm = br.com.genius.shiro.auth.MyCustomRealm
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false  
sha256Matcher.hashIterations = 1024  
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher  
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password, salt FROM User WHERE email = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select roleName from UserRole where email = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = select permission from RolesPermission where    roleName = ?
ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = x.x.x.x
ds.user = xxxx
ds.password = xxxx
ds.databaseName = data
jdbcRealm.dataSource=$ds
authc.usernameParam = email
authc.passwordParam = password
authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure
builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
[urls]  
/login = authc
/logout = logout
/admin/** = user, roles[admin]
/guest/** = user, roles[guest]`
```

in shiro.ini when has [ AUTH] it as the internal error , does not recognize and without it appears this error

```
`The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`


javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
    com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3936)
    com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4806)
    org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:52)
    org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:80)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:204)
    org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:727)
    org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:753)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking...

Comment: when accessing it from the file not found error

Comment: PUT IN several places the shiro.ini but still can not find .
would do instead of shiro.ini put on table

Comment: @DiegoSantos It seems you are having trouble expressing your problem. Perhaps you want to try http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Your stack trace shows that you haven't set any realm to your securityManager. You need at least one realm for a securityManager instance. If you are using .ini file you can configure like this

Comment: I put the shiro.ini file, but apparently the system does not find the file or putting "classpath: shiro.ini"

Answer (score 0):

If your application is looking on the classpath for shiro.ini, the directory src/main/webapp/web-inf is not the right path to put it.

Looks like you're using maven, if so, it should go in src/main/resources.
In the generated webapp it should end up in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: ok, thanks, now appeared more of a problem , the following error

Comment: Configuration error. Specified object [authc] with property [loginUrl] without first defining that object's class. Please first specify the class property first, e.g. myObject = fully_qualified_class_name and then define additional properties.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configuration error.  Specified object [authc] with property [loginUrl] without first defining that object's class.  Please first specify the class property first, e.g. myObject = fully_qualified_class_name and then define additional properties

Comment: my system interprets the redirection to link "/example" and redirects to the page "exemplo.jsp"

Comment: as put it in shiro.ini instead of own page link

Comment: edit the original question with a readable error and description and your shiro.ini

Comment: follows shiro.ini file

Comment: Can you please also edit your question to add a readable error, it is very unclear right now what the problem is

Comment: You are missing the commons-logging.jar in your classpath